# Testing server side validation in an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a AngularJS app with a Web API. I've implemented server side validation that I'd like to test on a submit of a form. Is there a way I could temporarily remove the AngularJS validators (`ng-required` etc) so that I test the server side validation?

I've tried disabling JS in the browser but JS needs to be enabled for Angular to work.

Comment: Try use tools for test like `Advanced REST Client` or similar to this tool.

Comment: Can you explain how that would help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [noValidate](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) attribute?